# How do I prefill fields in an envelope created from a template using Docusign's REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, docusignapi

Note: I'm using the 'classic' experience because the new interface doesn't have a way for a template to set up required fields for future signers.

The workflow:

- have a template with a bunch of fields
- using the api:

  - create an envelope/document from the template, and assign a new user to sign (this document is going to be an agreement for signing up for a service)

    - create new role
    - set roleName to fake signer on template (because I can't configure fields without at least one signer on the template)
    - add textTabs to try to perfill some of the fields.
  - retrieve the recipients
  - create a recipient view so that I get the URL to put in an iframe

This is kind of obnoxious, because I don't care about having a first signer that isn't the user signing up for the service. I would however, like to have the the document be copied to someone after signing, but docusign doesn't appear to support this (that I've found anyway).

Here is the node.js code for the creation of the envelope (where I think my API usage is going wrong):

```
function createEnvelopeDefinition(templateId, userData) {
  var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
  envDef.setEmailSubject('Signup Agreement');
  envDef.setTemplateId(templateId);

  var tRole = new docusign.TemplateRole();
  tRole.setRoleName('RoleOne');
  tRole.setName(userData.fullName);
  tRole.setEmail(userData.email);
  tRole.setClientUserId('2');
  tRole.setTabs(new docusign.Tabs());
  tRole.getTabs().setTextTabs([]);

  const fieldsToPreFill = [
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'field3',
    'field4'];

  fieldsToPreFill.forEach(fieldName => {
    let textTab = new docusign.Text();
    let value = userData[fieldName];
    if (value === null || value === undefined) { value = 'not null'; }
    textTab.setTabLabel(fieldName);
    textTab.setValue(value);
    tRole.getTabs().getTextTabs().push(textTab);
  });

  tRole = removeNulls(tRole);

  envDef.setTemplateRoles([tRole]);

  // send the envelope by setting |status| to 'sent'.
  // To save as a draft set to 'created'
  //   sent is required for getting view URLs
  envDef.setStatus('sent');

  return envDef;
}
```

In the template editor on docusign, the  `Data Field Tag Properties` show the label of each of the corresponding fields as `field1`, `field2`, etc.

These fields are now filled out with the provided values when I throw the new envelope in an iframe.

just for reference here is the rest of the code that creates the api connection, and gets the view URL

```
import ENV from 'environment/backend';
const accountId = ENV.docusign.accountId;
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var docusign = require('docusign-esign');

export function newApiClient() {
  let apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  apiClient.setBasePath(ENV.docusign.endpoint);

  // create JSON formatted auth header
  let creds = JSON.stringify({
    Username: ENV.docusign.email,
    Password: ENV.docusign.password,
    IntegratorKey: ENV.docusign.integratorKey
  });

  apiClient.addDefaultHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication', creds);

  // assign api client to the Configuration object
  // this probably doesn't need to be set every time...
  docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);

  return apiClient;
}

const defaultApiClient = newApiClient();
const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();

const createEnvelope = Promise.promisify(envelopesApi.createEnvelope, { context: envelopesApi });
const listRecipients = Promise.promisify(envelopesApi.listRecipients, { context: envelopesApi });
const createRecipientView = Promise.promisify(envelopesApi.createRecipientView, { context: envelopesApi });

export default defaultApiClient;

// promise resolves to the view URL, envelopeId for the user.
// returns a recipientView
export function setupDocumentForEmbeddedSigning(templateId, userData) {
  let envDefinition = createEnvelopeDefinition(templateId, userData);

  return createEnvelope(accountId, envDefinition, null)
    .then(envelopeSummary => {
      const envelopeId = envelopeSummary.envelopeId;

      return createViewFromEnvelope(envelopeId);
    });
}

export function createViewFromEnvelope(envelopeId) {
  return getRecipients(envelopeId).then(recipients => {
    // the last signer is the one we added in the
    // createEnvelopeDefinition step
    let signers = recipients.signers;
    let lastSigner = signers[signers.length - 1];

    return createView(envelopeId, lastSigner)
      .then(recipientView => [recipientView.url, envelopeId]);
  });
}

function getRecipients(envelopeId) {
  return listRecipients(accountId, envelopeId);
}

function createView(envelopeId, signerData) {
  var viewRequest = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();
  viewRequest.setReturnUrl(ENV.host);
  viewRequest.setAuthenticationMethod('email');

  // recipient information must match embedded recipient info
  // from the createEnvelopeDefinition method
  viewRequest.setEmail(signerData.email);
  viewRequest.setUserName(signerData.name);
  viewRequest.setRecipientId('2');
  viewRequest.setClientUserId('2');

  return createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);
}

// bug with the api wrapper
// https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/issues/47
const removeNulls = function(obj) {
  var isArray = obj instanceof Array;
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] === null) isArray ? obj.splice(k, 1) : delete obj[k];
    else if (typeof obj[k] == 'object') removeNulls(obj[k]);
    if (isArray && obj.length == k) removeNulls(obj);
  }
  return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

So, I may not fully understand where you're stuck, but I'll take a crack at this anyway...

Let's say I create a Template using the DocuSign UI and define two Recipient roles:

- **Signer1** (which will be the person who is signing up for your service) -- *Action* = "Sign"
- **CarbonCopy1** (which will be the person who gets a copy of the completed/signed documents once **Signer1** signs) -- *Action* = "Receive a Copy"

(Note: these roles can be named whatever you want to name them -- I named them "Signer1" and "CarbonCopy1" so it'd be clear who each role represents.)

Assuming the above scenario, your Template's Recipient Roles (in the DocuSign UI) will look like this:

[image]

Next, let's assume that you define some fields (tabs) in the Template's document(s) (i.e., using the DocuSign UI) that the **Signer1** recipient will need to populate when they sign the document(s). For this example, let's assume that the *label* (name) of one of those Text tabs is ***field1***. Notice that the field is assigned to the **Signer1** recipient:

[image]

Now, if I want to create an Envelope via the API that uses this Template, and pre-fill fields for one or more of the recipients, the key to doing that is using the "Composite Templates" structure in the API request. (See the *Composite Templates* section of [this page](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) for details.)  In the example described above, your **compositeTemplates** object in the API request would contain a single **serverTemplate** object (which specifies the *templateId* and *sequence*=1), and a single **inlineTemplate** object (which specifies *sequence*=2 and the recipient info, including values for any tabs (fields) that you want to pre-fill).

In the example described above, the JSON API request to create the Envelope would look like this (assuming we're just pre-filling a single field for **Signer1** -- obviously you could pre-fill additional fields by simply including them in the **tabs** object of the request along with *field1*):

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi//v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes

{
    "emailSubject": "Test Pre-fill Tabs",
    "emailBlurb": "This is a test.",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "CD0E6D53-3447-4A9E-BBAF-0EB2C78E8310"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates":[{
            "sequence": "2",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [
                    {
                        "roleName": "Signer1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "name": "John Doe",
                        "email": "johndoe@test.com",
                        "clientUserId": "1234",
                        "tabs": {
                            "textTabs": [
                                {
                                    "tabLabel": "field1",
                                    "value": "TEST-123"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                      "roleName": "CarbonCopy1",
                      "recipientId": "2",
                      "name": "Jane Doe",
                      "email": "janedoe@test.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }]
    }],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Once I create the Envelope using the above request, I execute a "POST Recipient View" request to get the signing URL for the first recipient (`https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi//v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId/views/recipient`).

Then, when I subsequently use the URL that's returned in that response to launch the signing session for **Signer1** (John Doe), I see that the **field1** tab is indeed pre-filled with the value that I specified in the "Create Envelope" API request (*TEST-123*):

[image]

Furthermore, once John Doe (**Signer1**) finishes signing and submits the completed documents, Jane Doe (**CarbonCopy1**) will be sent a copy.

I'm not familiar with the DocuSign Node SDK, but imagine you can figure out the syntax to use composite templates as shown in the above example. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting an error now :-(  `"{
↵  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
↵  "message": "Non-static method requires a target."
↵}"
`

Here is how is my json that I'm using to create the envelope with: http://pastie.org/10926040

Docusign's errors are suuuuuper helpful. lol

Comment: so, that is the error you get when you send don't send the envelope definition. :-\

now that I'm actually sending it, I get `"The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."`

Comment: Are you getting this error on the "Create Envelope" request or the "Post Recipient View" request? I'd suggest capturing a trace of the outbound request (using Fiddler or something similar) to troubleshoot -- compare the recipients portion of your request with the results of a "Get Recipients" request to ensure that you're specifying the right role name, etc.

Comment: in the create envelope view.

I did manage to get this working with my old code by removing the name and email in docusign. (apparently that was my problem the whole time). So, you did help me with the docusign configuration side of things!

Comment: That error message on the create recipient view operation is usually easy to resolve -- your request is simply not specifying recipient info correctly.  if you're so inclined, you can troubleshoot by comparing the recipient property values in your request with the properties of that user in a "Get Recipients" response for that envelope. (If you search SO for "[docusignapi] The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope" you'll see a few prior posts/answers about this issue.)