# Prefill fields in envelope from templates on DocuSign eSignature API

Tags: postman, docusignapi

I am trying to push data into tabs on a template that I created on the DocuSign UI, I want to be able to fill those tabs with the information I want, by using an API call.

I'm currently using postman to test this, and I have the following code on the body request, and the URL used from the signature API is https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/6053c210-xxx-xxx-xxx-bb5d4c55ebb3/envelopes

```
{
"emailBlurb": "Create an envelope with a templateId",
"emailSubject": "Template",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "042ff1ab-2c87-4410-96ac-05c02d13b969"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "rodrigoesgmail.com",
                            "name": "Rodrigo Test API",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "roleName": "seller",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                            {
                                "tabLabel": "field1",
                                "value": "TEST-123"
                            }
                        ]
                                
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sequence": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "sent"
```

}

The request goes through and returns the envelope ID and a 200 code which means it gets created and I also receive the email on both, the recipient defined on the template, and on the one defined on the API call, however, the tab I created on the request body, does not get created on my template on the document anywhere, so the tab with value "TEST-123" does not get populated on the template once it gets sent. I got this post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667986/how-do-i-prefill-fields-in-an-envelope-created-from-a-template-using-docusigns) but did not have success on it, am I missing something or does anyone know how to get what I want to be done?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a tab value for a tab that is in the template already?

In that case, your JSON looks good to me, with the caveat that your API call's value for the `tabLabel` attribute ***must exactly match*** the `Data label` value set for the tab in the template.

So in the DocuSign web app, you need to check that the Data label field is set to exactly `field1` with the same capitalization.

Here's a [live working example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Template%20with%20embedded%20recipient%20and%20setting%20a%20tab%20value) that sets the value of a tab defined in the template. The example also changes a recipient in the template to become an embedded recipient. But that's beside the point.

### Dynamically adding a new tab

You can also use composite templates to add a brand new tab to the envelope. You just need to define the tab and include the document ID that the tab will be placed on, the page number, x, and y values. Example:

```
"envelopeDefinition": {
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
      {
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "serverTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "36f7e831-9228-4273-929e-f047c133c08b"
          }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
          {
            "sequence": "1",
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                  "clientUserId": "1000",
                  "email": "name@example.com",
                  "name": "Signer Name",
                  "roleName": "signer",
                  "recipientId": "1",
                  "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [
                      {
                        "tabLabel": "signer_title",
                        "value": "Manager"
                      },
                      {
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "locked": "true",
                        "value": "Added via the API. Office:",
                        "font": "Helvetica",
                        "fontSize": "Size12",
                        "pageNumber": "3",
                        "xPosition": "40",
                        "yPosition": "428"
                      }
                    ],
                    "listTabs": [
                      {
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "font": "Helvetica",
                        "fontSize": "Size12",
                        "locked": "false",
                        "required": "false",
                        "pageNumber": "3",
                        "xPosition": "190",
                        "yPosition": "428",
                        "listItems": [
                          {
                            "text": "San Francisco",
                            "value": "SF"
                          },
                          {
                            "text": "London",
                            "value": "LON"
                          },
                          {
                            "text": "Paris",
                            "value": "PAR"
                          },
                          {
                            "text": "Jerusalem",
                            "value": "JLM"
                          },
                          {
                            "text": "São Paulo",
                            "value": "SP"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```